# How can I track virtual Disk device to physical slot?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I'm kind of new working with Unix (Ubuntu). I managed to install Ubuntu on RAID1 and mounted 3 RAID 0 drives. I have a 9271-8i storage controller:

```
RAID1 (sda) - Unix installed
RAID0 (sdb)
RAID0 (sdc)
RAID0 (sdd)
```

I'm trying to track virtual drives (sdb, sdc, sdd) to the actual physical slot.  If I see sdb is bad, I need to know which drive it is exactly on the server (I only have chance to do with the Device Id/Slot Id).

How to get the physical drive/Slot ID? Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have noted that there is a lot of information available via a simple google.  I will not recopy anothers' work here however.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in sda sdb sdc sdd ; do
     echo $i
     sudo hdparm -I $i | fgrep Serial\ Number;
done
```

And of course make sure you have labeled the serial number on the side of the drive visible without extracting the full drive.